# Do C++ POD types have RTTI?

Tags: c++, rtti, vtable

As I understand how RTTI is implemented in various C++ compilers (such as GCC), a pointer to the `type_info` data is stored in the `vtable` data of each class.

And also as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963926/when-is-a-vtable-created-in-c), POD type may not have a `vtable`.

But if POD types may not have a `vtable` then where is the pointer to the `type_info` stored? I know it is implementation-specific, but it would be better to be aware of a C++ compiler (such as GCC) internals.

Comment: The pointer would be statically determined, right? Since there's nothing dynamic to consider.

Comment: "it whould be better to be aware of a C++ compiler (such as GCC) internals." Well, both GCC and Clang are open source, so you can just look into it.

Comment: AFAIK, no. [see this code](http://ideone.com/2ZGeJS)

Comment: To clarify Kerrek's statement: POD types do have `type_info`,  but don't have RTTI, and that's possible because `type_info` isn't always RTTI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two kinds of types (for the purposes of RTTI): polymorphic types and non-polymorphic types. A polymorphic type is a type that has a virtual function, in itself or inherited from a base class. A non-polymorphic type is *everything else*; this includes POD types, but it includes many other types too.

If you have a pointer/reference to a polymorphic type `T`, and you call `typeid` on it, the `type_info` you get back is not necessarily the `type_info` you would get back for `typeid(T{})`. Instead, it is the *true* dynamic type of the object: the most derived class.

If you have a pointer/reference to a **non**-polymorphic type `T`, `typeid` will *always* return the `type_info` for `T` itself. Non-polymorphic types always assume that the pointer/reference is exactly its static type.

POD types are non-polymorphic, but a huge number of other types are non-polymorphic as well.