# Is type_info not a part of RTTI?

Tags: c++, gcc, rtti

I had asked a question [Do C++ POD types have RTTI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342258/do-c-pod-types-have-rtti) and someone told me in the comments:

> POD types do have type_info, but don't have RTTI, and that's possible
>   because type_info isn't always RTTI.

and it seems right as i could get the `type_info` of a POD (*non-polymorphic*) type.

But while I compile this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    std::cout << typeid(X) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

with flag `-fno-rtti` of GCC:

```
$ g++ -fno-rtti main.cpp && ./main
```

It won't compile:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:26: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
     std::cout << typeid(X) << std::endl;
                          ^
```

Does that mean `type_info` is a part of RTTI, or is it just a *behavior* of GCC?

Comment: RTTI means "runtime type information". It doesn't say anything about polymorphism. It's just about having information about types at runtime.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Someone else had told me: "_RTTI is only available for polymorphic classes._", this is the answer i got for my first question: "_Do C++ POD types have RTTI?_".

Comment: I am sorry about that.

Comment: The answer you accepted to that other question says otherwise, and explains how RTTI works for polymorphic and non-polymorphic types.

Comment: _"Does that mean type_info is a part of RTTI"_ `type_info` is just a class; did you mean `typeid`? Can you clarify either way?

Comment: @black: I means `type_info` class which is instantiated (or generated) by compiler for each type, and we can access it via `typeid()`.

Comment: I gave a misleading answer on the referred question. Sorry for that, I deleted it now. The accepted answer explains it much better.

Answer (score 5):

### Abstract

RTTI per se is not something really formally defined: C++ only says what `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` do, not how they're implemented. However, it is convenient indeed to group such kind of operations under a common name which is RTTI.

Notice an implementation is *not* required to strictly obtain this information at runtime i.e.

`if ( typeid(int) == typeid(double) )`

could also be determined during the program evaluation, much like `std::is_same`. `int` is undeniably non-polymorphic (it has no 'dynamic' type). [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) even claims:

> When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a typeid expression may involve runtime overhead (a virtual table lookup), **otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time.**

But it's to be taken cautiously.

---

> Does that mean type_info is a part of RTTI, or is it just a behavior of GCC?

`type_info` is a *class*. You may not construct any object of that type - you only can through `typeid`.

[`-fno-rtti`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) disable RTTI under GCC: you can't use `typeid`, and thereby neither can be `type_info`. They're very close each other.

To conclude, the original quote is totally right:

> POD types do have `type_info`, but don't have RTTI, and that's possible because type_info isn't always RTTI.

The runtime information is available through `typeid`. There is just nothing dynamic to consider (indeed, `dynamic_cast` would make no sense).

Comment: RTTI is the normative term used by [Itanium C++ ABI](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/cxxabi-1.86.html#rtti), which is G++ conforming to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of "RTTI" in the standard. Instead, it's said in different words.

- `<typeinfo>` is referred to as "dynamic type identification" in [support.general]
- [intro.object] says: "Some objects are *polymorphic* (10.3); the implementation generates information associated with each such object that makes it possible to determine that object’s type during program execution"
- [expr.dynamic.cast] talks about checks that happen at "run-time". All other uses of "runtime" in the standard refer to something else.

[expr.typeid] explains what `typeid` does:

> 2 When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a
>   polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a `std::type_info`
>   object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that
>   is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers. ...

The latter is typically referred to a "run-time" operation.

> 3 When `typeid` is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a
>   polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object
>   representing the static type of the expression. ... The expression is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5).

While the former can be seen as a "compile-time" operation.

Regardless, GCC doesn't really care and disables `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` altogether if you use the `-fno-rtti` flag:

[rtti.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/5d4b30ea56c1733a9149b59105b9645c115cc123/gcc/cp/rtti.c#L285):

```
  if (! flag_rtti)
    {
      error ("cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti");
      return false;
    }
```

Could it disable `typeid` for polymorphic types only? Sure. But we're going to go with occam's razor in that it's much easier developmentally-wise to prevent the use of `typeid` altogether.